# Manipulate Afx OLE Control in External Window

Tags: powershell, user-interface, winapi, automation, ui-automation

I have to manipulate (including get and set text from) an accounting system using Powershell.

The process has a window which contain a grid-like container (the one with blue background colour in the screenshot).

The container contains some Text fields and Combo-boxes.

I tried different ways to get the UI controls(The Text fields/'Edit' Controls in the container).

[image]

I tried UIAutomation as follow but fail to found any Text field/'Edit' Control but found the Comobo-box.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName UIAutomationClient

$ele=[System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement]::FromHandle($hwnd)
$elecol=$ele.FindAll([System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope]::Descendants, 
    [System.Windows.Automation.Condition]::TrueCondition)
for ($i=0;$i -lt $elecol.count;$i++){$elecol[$i].Current} #Only found Scroll Bars & Combo
```

If look into the  "AutomationElement.Current"  of container itself ($ele.Current), it looks like the following.

```
ControlType          : System.Windows.Automation.ControlType
LocalizedControlType : pane
Name                 : 
AcceleratorKey       : 
AccessKey            : 
HasKeyboardFocus     : False
IsKeyboardFocusable  : False
IsEnabled            : True
BoundingRectangle    : 350,1658,2830,443
HelpText             : 
IsControlElement     : True
IsContentElement     : True
LabeledBy            : 
AutomationId         : 
ItemType             : 
IsPassword           : False
ClassName            : AfxGWOleControl42
NativeWindowHandle   : 3409268
ProcessId            : 11656
IsOffscreen          : False
Orientation          : None
FrameworkId          : Win32
IsRequiredForForm    : False
ItemStatus           :
```

And if looks into the supported Patterns ($ele.GetSupportedPatterns()) of the container, it shows nothing.

I also tried using WinAPI to Enum All Child Windows but found No Text field/'Edit' Control too.

```
function Enum-ChildWindows{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    [intPtr]$Hwnd
    )

    BEGIN{

        if (("EnumChildWindowsAPI" -as [type]) -eq $null){
        Add-Type  @"
            using System; // namespace "IntPtr"
            using System.Runtime.InteropServices; // namespace "DLLImport"
            using System.Collections.Generic; // namespace "List"

            public class EnumChildWindowsAPI
            {
                [DllImport("user32")]
                [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
                public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumWindowProc callback, IntPtr i);
                public static List<IntPtr> GetChildWindows(IntPtr parent)
                {
                    List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
                    GCHandle listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);
                try
                {
                    EnumWindowProc childProc = new EnumWindowProc(EnumWindow);
                    EnumChildWindows(parent, childProc,GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (listHandle.IsAllocated)
                    listHandle.Free();
                }
                    return result;
                }
                private static bool EnumWindow(IntPtr handle, IntPtr pointer)
                {
                    GCHandle gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(pointer);
                    List<IntPtr> list = gch.Target as List<IntPtr>;
                    if (list == null)
                    {
                    throw new InvalidCastException("GCHandle Target could not be cast as List<IntPtr>");
                    }
                    list.Add(handle);

                    return true;
                }
                public delegate bool EnumWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr parameter);
            }
"@
        }
    }

    PROCESS{

        return [EnumChildWindowsAPI]::GetChildWindows($Hwnd)

    }
}
```

And of course, sending WM_SETTEXT message to the container is also not working.

Watching into the Spy++, the class name of the grid-like container is "afxGWOleControl", shown as follow.

[image]

[image]

An interesting thing is, the combo box "window" appear in Spy++ only when it is on selected.

Is there any way to edit/read the text field inside the container?

Comment: You can use [**Inspect.exe**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) to see if you can find these *Text fields/'Edit' Controls*.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Perfect! It’s MSAA based.

Comment: So has this issue been solved? :)

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Still not yet. I found that the Text field/Edit Control seems dynamically created when it is selected. But the blue background container is obviously a ControlType.Datagrid but shown as pane in both MSAA mode and UIAutomation mode. I even cannot count the number of rows of the Grid.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT

See the following screenshots.

(MSAA)
Text field unselected - https://imgur.com/f5wTczg
(MSAA)
Text field selected - https://imgur.com/BGaHkSR

(UIAutomation)
Text field unselected - https://imgur.com/iDfuaNf
(UIAutomation) Text field selected - https://imgur.com/GuyxAzO

Comment: From your screenshot (*(UIAutomation) Text field selected*), the edit control is inside of a pane control. Find pane control and set focus before you can edit the text field. Refer to ["UI Automation Support for the Pane Control Type"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-support-for-the-pane-control-type) and ["Add Content to a Text Box Using UI Automation"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/add-content-to-a-text-box-using-ui-automation).